# Ag-Grid sass/webpack does not seem to resolve relative path from inside node_modules

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, webpack-4, node-sass, vue-cli-3

If I use this in a `.vue` component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-material/sass/ag-theme-material';
</style>
```

I get this error:

```
./icons/aggregation.svg?color1=%23333333&color2= in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modu
les/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modul
es/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_module
s/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./path/to/my/Component.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=
f7f0e260&lang=scss&scoped=true&
```

I am using

```
"ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-vue": "^20.0.0",
"vue": "^2.5.21",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",

"@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.0",
```

What am I forgetting or doing wrong?

Comment: Might be useful. Check this - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/363